# Format value to float with width and precision

Tags: python, floating-point

I would like to validate a string input to verify if it could be formated to a valid float for given width and precision.

```
width = 10
precision = 4

value = '12'

try:
   "{10.4f}".format(value)
except:
   print "not valid"
```

this test fails but it should works because `12` could be considered as a float `12.0000`

**I would also like to have a dynamic test because width and precision are variables.**

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot the `:` colon:

```
"{:10.4f}".format(float(value))
```

otherwise Python interprets the first digit as a positional parameter index.

Each parameter can be set with it's own placeholder:

```
"{value:{width}.{precision}f}".format(
    value=float(value), width=width, precision=precision)
```

`width` and `precision` arguments are interpolated before the `value` is formatted.

This is, however, not a good test for floating point inputs. The float value `12.234` cannot be exactly represented; binary fractions can only approximate it:

```
>>> format(12.234, '.53f')
'12.23399999999999998578914528479799628257751464843750000'
```

so this value wouldn't 'fit' your 10.4 constraints, yet look when rounded like a perfectly valid input to give.

**Any** floating point value can be formatted to a fixed width, in any case:

```
>>> format(10**11 + 0.1, '10.4f')
'100000000000.1000'
```

No `ValueError` will be raised; the `10` in the width parameter means: *produce a string that is at least this many characters wide, pad with spaces if it is shorter*, and this width *includes* the decimal point and the decimals.

To validate floating point input, the best you can do is test that it can be converted to a float, and then test for mininum and maxmimum values:

```
try:
    value = float(value)
except ValueError:
    # cannot be converted to a valid float
    return "Not a valid input"
else:
    if 0 <= value < 10 ** 11:
        return "Value out of range"
```

Comment: yes thank you. How can I change 10 and 4 for variables?

Comment: thanks for your perfect answer! Can you tell why there is leading spaces before the formated value when doing a print ?

Comment: @BelowtheRadar: You specified a width; you are printing the floating point value to a width of at least 10 characters (including the 4 decimals and the decimal point); any value that ends up shorter than that is padded with whitespace. The width does *not* mean "round the value down to 10 digits before the decimal point"..

Answer (score 2):

Let's use Python 3

[Format Specifier](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) `f"{var}"`

```
>>> width = 10
>>> precision = 4
>>> value = decimal.Decimal("12.34567")
>>> f"result: {value:{width}.{precision}}"  # nested fields
'result:      12.35'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a type mismatch here I think ...

```
value = 12
```

not

```
value = '12'
```

Comment: Hi, the input is a string that I want to try to format to float

Answer (score 0):

First, instead of

```
"{10.4f}".format(value)
```

write it as:
    "{10.4f}".format(float(value))

to convert to string to float first

On how to generalize this: instead of having the string "{10.4f}" hard-coded, create it

```
width = 10
precision = 4
formatting_string = '{' + str(width) + '.' + str(precision) + 'f}'
```

The, use

```
formatting_string.format(float(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using string rjust and ljust:

```
value.rjust(width)+'.'.ljust(precision+1,'0')+'f'
```

Output:

```
        12.0000f
```

In this way, we donot need to convert the `value` to float